# Does two loops fuse if there exists both true dependence and anti dependency among them

Tags: loops, dependencies, compiler-optimization

1st loop with one statement
`A[i,j]=B[i-1,j];`

2nd loop with just one statement
`B[i,j]=A[i,j];`

Can I fuse these two independent loops to a single loop.

Is it legal??

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot combine them into a single loop, as the following Python test program shows:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

for i in range(1,len(a)):
    a[i] = b[i-1]
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    b[i] = a[i]
print a, b

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

for i in range(1,len(a)):
    a[i] = b[i-1]
    b[i] = a[i]
print a, b
```

The output of that gives you two *different* results:

```
[1, 5, 6, 7] [5, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 5, 5, 5] [5, 5, 5, 5]
```

The reason why they're not equivalent is because, in the two-loop solution `a[n]` is set based on the *original* value of `b[n-1]`.

In the one-loop solution, `a[n]` is set based on the updated value of `b[n-1]`.

And `b[n-1]` will have been changed in the previous iteration of the loop.